Test if the series converge $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ using Cauchy's convergence test
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$
Obviously, this is the p-series (hyperharmonic series) with $p=\frac{1}{2} < 1$ which means that it is divergent, so that's what I'm going to try to prove with the following criterion, which is the negation of the Cauchy's convergence test:

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ diverge iff $\exists\; \varepsilon > 0 \space \forall\; N \in \mathbb{N} \space \exists\; p,n \in \mathbb N \colon \require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{p \geq n} n \geq N$ such that $|a_{n+1} + \dots + a_{n+p}| \geq \varepsilon$

Working backwards as usual, I start with $$\Bigl| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+p}} \Bigr| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+p}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}},\; \forall\; n$$
Now for a choice of $\varepsilon = 1/2$, we can choose $n=1$ and let $p \in \mathbb N$ be fixed. Then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} > \frac{1}{2}$.
I'm not sure if this is on the right track and if I should have done anything with $N$, perhaps just say "let N > 1" "let $N = n - 1$"?

You might do better with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+p}} \geq \frac{p}{\sqrt{n+p}}$

@Henry I did consider that, but having not to deal with $p$ seemed simpler no? hence why I went with the above

@powerline unfortunately, as $a_n \to 0$, we have to deal with $p$ - taking fixed-length segments will not be enough.

We can't choose $n = 1$, as we need $n \geq N$. And $\forall N$ means that after we choose $\epsilon$, our argument should work for any $N$, we can't choose it ourselves.
Inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+p}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ is too weak. But $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+p}} \geq \frac{p}{\sqrt{n+p}}$ is enough.
Choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, $n = N$ and $p = n$. We get $\sum\limits_{i=n}^{n + p} \frac{1}{\sqrt i} \geq \frac{n}{\sqrt {2n}} \geq \frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt 2} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} = \epsilon$.

@Henry yes, I copied parts of OP's post without noticing that they use $p$ as number of terms rather than upper bound. I am now curious if this version of Cauchy criteria (that requires number of terms to be greater than number of first term) is actually true...

hm perhaps the requirement $p \geq n$ is unnecessary (and even wrong)? I see now there isn't such condition in my notes but I got confused with the positive statement of another version of the test that has "$\forall m, n : m \geq n $"...

It's not necessary, but gives equivalent statement (and I think it's a reasonable exercise to prove it).
